# join lists by their members' names

Tags: r

Imagine I have several lists with the same structure, e.g.:

```
list1 <- list(foo="abc", bar=1:3)
list2 <- list(foo="def", bar=5:7)
```

so, their contents look like this:

```
> list1
$foo
[1] "abc"

$bar
[1] 1 2 3

> list2
$foo
[1] "def"

$bar
[1] 4 5 6
```

I would like to combine them so the result should look like this:

```
> list3
$foo
[1] "abc" "def"

$bar
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

What would be the best way to do this? I tried some combinations of `c(list1, list2)`, `list(list1, list2)` etc. Or the only solution would be to write my own function which will scan all members of both lists and match their names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
Map(c, list1, list2)
```

It will also work with more than two lists:

```
Map(c, list1, list2, list3, list4, list5)
```

If you have all your lists in a higher level list, e.g.:

```
list_of_lists = list(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5)
```

then you can do:

```
do.call(Map, c(f = c, list_of_lists))
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that the names must be in the same order. `lists <- list(list1, rev(list2)); do.call(Map, c(f=c, lists))`

Comment: `lapply(list_of_lists, function(x) x[names(list_of_lists[[1]])] )` - @RichardScriven - something like that first would get it sorted.